# Is there a Typst equivalent for LaTeX's special page figure placement?

Tags: typst

In LaTeX there's a handy placement option for figures that allows you to place them in another "special page", such that only figures appear in that page and they are vertically centered:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics{image.png}
\caption{My caption...}
\end{figure}
```

Is there a Typst equivalent of this?

Comment: This looks like a question that should be moved to https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NicoHaase: I don't think this question will reach its proper audience on https://tex.stackexchange.com/ as Typst has drastically different code semantics compared to TeX/LaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! You can add `#pagebreak` before and after the figure, or simply create a `page` container like the code below. `set align(center + horizon)` is what ensures the figure is vertically and horizontally centered on this new page.

```
#set page(height: 3in)
#let my-fig(..args, placement: none) = {
  if placement == page {
    page[
      #set align(center + horizon)
      #figure(..args)
    ]
  } else {
    figure(..args, placement: placement)
  }
}

#let pic = rect(width: 50%, height: 50%, radius: 1em, fill: aqua)

#lorem(30)

#my-fig(pic, caption: [top placement], placement: top)
#my-fig(pic, caption: [page placement], placement: page)

#lorem(100)
```

[image]

Comment: Okey, so it's completely manual. Thanks!

Comment: @GuillemVidalSerrats I've updated the answer to be less manual. In short, you can also wrap the `page` inside a custom function to handle page-wise alignment for multiple figures